# Write multiple lines from one line

Tags: vba, excel

Excel + VBA.

I have a file with 4 columns ID, No Spools, Packing / Delivery Lenght.
That I'm doing is writing the number of lines based on No Spools to another sheet (You can see the data in the "CreateOrders" sheet to understand better).
This is working properly, but I have a problem. I before in the "Due Date" sheet: "CreateOrders" was putting the "Today Date", but now want to put a specific date depending on the ID that is in the previous sheet "PROGRAMA COBRE", example:

From:

[image: From]

To:

[image: To]

My File: `http://speedy.sh/s4peR/Livro3.xlsm`

I did manually, put all the dates "by hand", but how can I do this automatically?

Thank you for help.

EDIT (my code):

```
Sub CreateOrdersFile()
    Dim c As Range, a As Long, No_Order As String, sh2 As Worksheet

    Set sh2 = Sheets("CreateOrders")
    No_Order = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the first Order Number (Today Date + 001)", Title:="Order Number required!")

    With sh2
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        .Range("A1:J1").Value = Array("No Order", "Due Date", "ID", "No Spools", "Packing Unit", "Quantity Unit", "Type", "Remark", "Storage Location", "Item No")
        .Range("A2").Value = No_Order
    End With

    For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        a = c.Value

        With sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(a, 3)
            .Value = Array(c.Offset(, -1).Value, 1, c.Offset(, 1).Value)
        End With

    Next c
        With sh2
            .Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillSeries
                With .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
                    '.Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                    .Offset(, 4).Value = "M"
                    .Offset(, 5).Value = "Order"
                    .Offset(, 7).Value = "POGU01"
                    .Offset(, 8).Value = 1
                End With
        End With
    MsgBox "Orders successfully created!", , "Orders Created"
End Sub
```

Comment: You may get a better response if you include the code or your attempt that you're having issue with in the question instead of just posting a link to a copy of your workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**Untested**)? Change your `For loop` to this

```
For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    a = c.Value

    With sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(a, 3)
        .Value = Array(c.Offset(, -1).Value, 1, c.Offset(, 1).Value)
    End With

    '~~> The below "should" fill the Column B with Dates.
    With sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(a, 1)
        .Value = c.Offset(, 2).Value
    End With
Next c
```